# How to pass the dynamic added values into servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I want to get this value

> name="product' + counter + '"

its a  dynamic values when i click to add it will crate another row, can any one tell me how to get this dynamic values and how should i pass to servlet and how can i get in servlet. 
i am using form submission : JSP and JAVA env.

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter++;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="linetotal' + counter + '" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        alert(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java and JSP? It looks like a JavaScript problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add counter, change your code like this.

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter++;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        alert(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });
```

And in `servlet` get the `array` of all `values` linked with each `input box` like below code.

```
String[] products = request.getParameterValues("product");
String[] prices= request.getParameterValues("price");
String[] qtys= request.getParameterValues("qty");
String[] linetotals = request.getParameterValues("linetotal");
```

**EDIT** Added complete code

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="validationform" name="validationform" method="get" action="BG_Form">

<table class="order-list" style="margin-left: 228px;">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Total</td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="product"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price">
            </td><td><input type="text" name="qty"></td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="linetotal"></td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="5">
                <input type="button" value="Add Product" name="addrow" id="addrow">

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                Grand Total: Rs<span id="grandtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        In Words <span id="inworDs" ></span>

        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="submit"/>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<form>



<script>
    $("#addrow").click(function(){
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
              var cols = "";
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
              newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting first value only. i m using this for (String string : products) {
  System.out.println("Hii Product "+string);
  
 } tell me any other way to iterate. Thanks again

Comment: Let me understand you are adding more than one rows on `ui` and getting only one value at server side. if this is the case then please add your entire jsp code.

Comment: Change your form method to `GET` `<form method="GET">` and examine what are the values are going for the key `product`

Comment: @BashaGhouse i think some .js files are missing fiddlw is not working properly. kindly add .js files i am unable to add rows

Comment: when i checked its going only one field: ?poNo=rere&toAddress=Basha&toWhomname=Saravana&product=Mango&price=33&qty=22&linetotal=726.00

Comment: @BashaGhouse I have added a sample html. Try this and confirmed is that working for you or not